TableCalendar widget does not correctly reflect updates to the UI
It has the data from the API get stored into selectedBookings, but the calendar table doesn't reflect this in the UI when selecting a day, Is there a mistake ?
Update: The table calendar shows a dot under the date, and the event loader is correctly fetching the data. However, when clicking to select a day, the details are not displayed.
Getx controller:
class BookingController extends GetxController {

  var bookingsData = <bookingItemModel>[].obs;
  Map<DateTime, List<bookingItemModel>> bookingsByDate = <DateTime, List<bookingItemModel>>{}.obs;
  RxList<bookingItemModel> selectedBookings = <bookingItemModel>[].obs;
  Rx<DateTime> selectedDate = DateTime.now().obs;
  var selectedDay = Rxn<DateTime>();

  var calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month.obs;

  var rangeStart = Rxn<DateTime>(); 
  var rangeEnd = Rxn<DateTime>(); 

  final DateFormat apiDateFormat = DateFormat('EEE, dd-MM-yyyy'); // Matches API format
  final DateFormat filterDateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');   // For comparison

  @override
  void onInit() async{
    super.onInit();
    await getBookingsData();
    selectedBookings;
  }

void selectDay(DateTime day) {
  final normalizedDay = DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day);
  print("Normalized Day Selected: $normalizedDay");

  if (bookingsByDate.containsKey(normalizedDay)) {
    print("Matching Key Found: $normalizedDay");
    selectedBookings.value = bookingsByDate[normalizedDay] ?? [];
    print("Bookings for Selected Date: ${selectedBookings.map((b) => b.name).toList()}");
  } else {
    print("No Matching Key Found for: $normalizedDay");
    selectedBookings.value = [];
  }
  selectedBookings.refresh();
  update();
  
   
}

void onFormatChanged(CalendarFormat format) {
  if (calendarFormat.value != format) {
    calendarFormat.value = format;
  }
}

Set<DateTime> holidays={
  DateTime(2024,10,31),
  DateTime(2024,12,25),
  DateTime(2025,1,1),
};

void onRangeSelected(DateTime? start, DateTime? end, DateTime focusedDay) {
    selectedDay.value = null;
    rangeStart.value = start;  
    rangeEnd.value = end;
    selectedDay.value = start;
    update();  
}

  Future<void> getBookingsData() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await Dio().get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/xxx.php");
      var bookings = bookingModel.fromJson(response.data);
      bookingsData.value = bookings.data!;

      bookingsByDate = {};
      DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('EEE, dd-MM-yyyy'); // Custom format
      print("Bookings fetched during init: ${bookingsData.length}");

      for (var booking in bookingsData) {
        try {
          DateTime date = formatter.parse(booking.orderDate!);
          date = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day);

          if (!bookingsByDate.containsKey(date)) {
            bookingsByDate[date] = [];
          }
          bookingsByDate[date]!.add(booking);
        } catch (e) {
          print('Invalid orderDate format for booking: ${booking.orderDate}');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching bookings data: $e');
    }
    update();
  }

}

Getx view:
class BookingView extends GetView<BookingController> {
  const BookingView({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeepAliveWrapper(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const Text(''),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,
        title: Text('Calendar'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Obx(() {
            return TableCalendar(
                eventLoader: (day) {
                print("Event loader called for: $day");
                DateTime normalizedDay = DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day);
                final events = controller.bookingsByDate[normalizedDay] ?? [];
                print("Events for $normalizedDay: ${events.map((e) => e.name).toList()}");
                return events;
              },
              locale: "en_US",
              firstDay: DateTime.utc(2020, 1, 1),
              lastDay: DateTime.utc(2100, 12, 31),
              focusedDay: controller.selectedDay.value ?? DateTime.now(),
              calendarFormat: controller.calendarFormat.value,
              holidayPredicate: (day) {
                return controller.holidays
                    .contains(DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day));
              },
              rangeSelectionMode: RangeSelectionMode.toggledOn,
              onRangeSelected: (start, end, focusedDay) {
                controller.onRangeSelected(start, end, focusedDay);
              },
              onFormatChanged: (format) {
                controller.onFormatChanged(format);
              },
              selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                final result = isSameDay(controller.selectedDay.value, day);
                print("Predicate check: $day == ${controller.selectedDay.value} -> $result");
                return result;
              },
              onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                controller.selectedDay.value = selectedDay;  // Update selectedDay
                focusedDay = focusedDay;
                controller.selectDay(selectedDay);
              },
              //onDaySelected: controller.selectDay,
              daysOfWeekHeight: ScreenAdapter.height(60.0),
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                  formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green.shade200,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.circular(ScreenAdapter.width(45))),
                  formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(30.0),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.green.shade700,
                  ),
                  leftChevronIcon: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.chevron_left,
                    color: Colors.green.shade200,
                  ),
                  rightChevronIcon: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.chevron_right,
                    color: Colors.green.shade200,
                  ),
                  formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                  titleCentered: false,
                  // titleTextFormatter: (date, locale) => DateFormat.yMMM(locale).format(date),
                  formatButtonVisible: true,
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                markerDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                markersAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                holidayDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                holidayTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45)),
                todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green.shade200, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                todayTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45)),
                rangeStartTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45),
                ),
                rangeEndTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45),
                ),
                withinRangeTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45)),
                weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45), color: Colors.red),
                outsideTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45), color: Colors.grey),
                defaultTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45)),
                weekNumberTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45)),
              ),
              daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
                weekdayStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45),
                ),
                weekendStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: ScreenAdapter.fontSize(45), color: Colors.red),
              ),
            );
          }),
          SizedBox(height: ScreenAdapter.height(20)), // Add spacing
          Expanded(
            child: Obx(() {
              print("Rebuilding Obx: ${controller.selectedBookings}");
              return controller.selectedBookings.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'No bookings for ${DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(controller.selectedDate.value)}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: controller.selectedBookings.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var booking = controller.selectedBookings[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(booking.name ?? 'No Name'),
                          subtitle:
                              Text('${booking.startTime} - ${booking.endTime}'),
                        );
                      },
                    );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

I sincerely appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide on this matter. Thank you very much for taking the time to help.
